# Perl regex to match metacharacters

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text file which is like following.

```
Jack       Boy
Jill       Girl
Jam        ????
John       Boy
Michelle   Girl
```

I have written this, which I intended to match only lines that contain two words and not the line `Jam   ????`. It is not working.

```
if ( $line =~ ( /(\w+)\s+(\w+)/ ) && !( m/\?\?\?\?/ ) )
```

Comment: Is this the full complexity of your data file and your requirement? Why does your regular expression capture the words?

Comment: how is it not working?

Comment: This is like `if ($answer eq 'yes' or 'no') { ... }`. I hope you see your mistake?

Answer (score 2):

If you are also *processing* the data then a regular expression is the *wrong tool* for this.

You should simply split each line into fields and check whether the second field contains nothing but question marks.

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
  my @fields = split ' ', $line;
  next unless $fields[1] =~ /[^?]/;
  print $line;
}

__DATA__
Jack       Boy
Jill       Girl
Jam        ????
John       Boy
Michelle   Girl
```

**output**

```
Jack       Boy
Jill       Girl
John       Boy
Michelle   Girl
```

Answer (score 1):

Are these the only two options: two words or a word and `????`?

If so, the first part `/(\w)+\s+(\w+)/` is enough.

`\w` doesn't match `?`.

Answer (score 0):

I see no need to match metacharacters for your specific input:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    print if /(\w+)\s+(\w+)/;
}

__DATA__
Jack       Boy
Jill       Girl
Jam        ????
John       Boy
Michelle   Girl
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers have covered that this isn't really the right process, but sometimes filtering strings by regular expression is helpful in a single if statement.

You almost had it! It's missing the matching operator in the second half of the if statement.

`if ($line =~ (/(\w+)\s+(\w+)/) && !($line =~ m/\?\?\?\?/))`

Comment: There is an answer that says exactly this. The author deleted it. In what circumstance would you suggest this instead of `split`?

Comment: None. `split` is the right way to handle it. That's why I upvoted your answer. I just wanted to make minimal changes so the OP could understand why the original code didn't work.